# Create a Share button on Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10 (Mobile)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10, unity-game-engine

How can I create a Share button (that share a defined mesage to another player contact) as the below image on **Windows Phone 8, 8.1 and 10 (Mobile)**:

[image]

To create this script to share on **Android Device** I use the following code:

```
public class ShareScript : MonoBehaviour {

    string subject = "Subject";
    string body = "Body";

    public void OnAndroidTextSharingClick()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ShareAndroidText());
    }
    IEnumerator ShareAndroidText()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        //execute the below lines if being run on a Android device
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            //Reference of AndroidJavaClass class for intent
            AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
            //Reference of AndroidJavaObject class for intent
            AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject ("android.content.Intent");
            //call setAction method of the Intent object created
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
            //set the type of sharing that is happening
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");
            //add data to be passed to the other activity i.e., the data to be sent
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
            //intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TITLE"), "Text Sharing ");
            intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);
            //get the current activity
            AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            //start the activity by sending the intent data
            AndroidJavaObject jChooser = intentClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("createChooser", intentObject, "Share Via");
            currentActivity.Call("startActivity", jChooser);
        #endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [DataTransferManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.aspx).[ShowShareUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.showshareui.aspx) to show the sharing pane.

Handle the DataTransferManager.[DataRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.datarequested.aspx) event to provide the data when the user choses to share.

```
private void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRequest request = e.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "Share Text Example";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "An example of how to share text.";
    request.Data.SetText("Hello World!");
}
```

See the [Share data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/share-data) docs on MSDN for more info.

In Unity you can call these in an #if NETFX_CORE block so it runs only when using the Windows Runtime and not Mono. See [Windows Store Apps: WinRT API in C# scripts](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-scripts.html). If you target Windows 10 then there are plug-ins at https://github.com/microsoft/unityplugins which include sharing. For earlier targets there are commercial plugins.

Comment: But how would the code in unity (C# script)? how I can append the `ShowShareUI` to button event, and how I can append the `DataRequested` to `ShowShareUI`

Comment: I insert the code but had various namespaces errors, I put the code and the errors on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/dzmM4z37

Comment: These are Windows Runtime calls which aren't available in mono. You'll need to put them in a plugin or use compile time checks (#if NETFX_CORE) to include them when building for Windows but exclude them in mono targets such as the Unity Editor.